# How can I make an inline for loops in python to sum a list of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did this for loop and I wanted to put it in only one line.

```
def mean(list):
    sum = 0
    for i in list:
        sum += i
    return sum // len(list)
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work, it is a syntax error.

```
def mean(list):
    sum = 0
    sum = [sum += i for i in list]
    return sum // len(list)
```

Comment: why not just use `sum(list)`?

Comment: Aside: please, don't use `sum` as a variable name, its a builtin function already. Same goes for `list`.

Comment: List comprehensions are for creating lists. They're not "inline for loops".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A faster (and better) way will be to use `built-in`s:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a)/len(a)
```

you cannot make a sum using a inline loop unless you use fancy hacks including the `:=` operator and list comphention.(**Not** recommended)

BTW,you should *never* use builtin names as variable names.They will make your code harder to understand,and (sometimes) slower.

**Edit:** If you *really* want the loop in one line,here's how to do it (python3.9+ needed)

```
def mean(a):
    s=0
    return [s:=s+i for i in a][-1]/len(a)
```